# Three-machine proportionate flow shop problem with unequal machine

Tags: c#, performance, dynamic-programming

As part of an academic project I wrote a code about dynamic programming that solves the "Three-machine proportionate flow shop problem with unequal machine".

> In flow shop scheduling it is usually assumed that the processing
> times of the operations belonging to the same job are unrelated. But
> when a job corresponds to producing a certain quantity of some good,
> then it is likely that the processing times are related to this
> quantity, and hence are constant except for some factor that depends
> on the speed of the machine. In this paper, we consider this special
> case of the flow shop problem, which we call the proportionate flow
> shop problem with unequal machine speeds. This is a special case of
> the flow shop problem with ordered processing times that has been
> studied by Smith, Panwalkar, and Dudek. Their results imply that
> makespan minimization is easy if the first or last machine is slowest;
> if the second machine is slowest, then there exists an optimum
> schedule that is V-shaped. We provide an algorithm that solves this
> problem (and the more general problem with ordered processing times)
> to optimality in pseudopolynomial time, and we show that this is best
> possible by establishing NP-hardness in the ordinary sense.
>
> [*ACM Digital Library*](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2308957)

My major problem is that the code takes a lot of time to calculate big values (bigger than 10).

1. What is the code efficiency?
2. How can I calculate it by myself?
3. How can I make this code specifically efficient?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PF_with_one_deferent_machine
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double[] jobs=new double[0];
            double[] mashines_rates = new double[0];
            int num_of_jobs=0;
            double[][] examples;
            double[][] p;
            double[] sorted; 
            //getting input from user
            //jobs = new double[3] { 2, 4, 7 };
            //mashines_rates = new double[4] { 1, 1, 0.5, 1 };

            Console.WriteLine("0 - auto     1 - manual");
            Console.Write("Auto or manual input? ");
            Boolean manual=(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())==1);
            if (manual)
            {
                #region Input manual
                Console.Write("How many jobs you have? ");
                num_of_jobs = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                jobs = new double[num_of_jobs];
                for (int size = 1; size <= num_of_jobs; size++)
                {
                    Console.Write("The process time of job number " + size+": ");
                    jobs[size-1] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("How many machines you have? ");
                int num_of_machines = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                mashines_rates = new double[num_of_machines];
                for (int size = 1; size <= num_of_machines; size++)
                {
                    Console.Write("The rate time of the machine number " + size + ": ");
                    mashines_rates[size - 1] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                }
            #endregion
                manualRun(jobs, mashines_rates);

                sorted = jobs;
                MergeSort_Recursive(sorted, 0, jobs.Length - 1); //sort array from small to big
                Array.Reverse(sorted);  //reverse array (from big to small in this case)
                p = MakeP(sorted, mashines_rates);
                DynamicProgramming(p);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }else{
                #region Auto input 
                Console.Write("How many examples do you want to run? ");
                int num_of_ex= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("How many jobs you have? ");
                num_of_jobs = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("What is maximum job value? ");
                int maximum = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("How many machines you have? ");
                int num_of_machines = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                mashines_rates = new double[num_of_machines];
                for (int size = 1; size <= num_of_machines; size++)
                {
                    Console.Write("The rate time of the machine number " + size + ": ");
                    mashines_rates[size - 1] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                examples = new double[num_of_ex][];
                Random random = new Random();
                //int maximum = 10;
                int minimum = 1;

                for (int i = 0; i < num_of_ex; i++)
                {
                    examples[i] = new double[num_of_jobs];
                    for (int j = 0; j < num_of_jobs; j++)
                    {
                        //examples[i][j] = random.NextDouble() * (maximum - minimum) + minimum;
                        examples[i][j] = random.Next(minimum,maximum);
                    }
                }
            #endregion 
                CreateOutputFile(autoRun(examples, mashines_rates));
            }
         }

        private static void DynamicProgramming(double[][] p)
        {

            int j = p[0].Length-1;
            int num_t1_options=Convert.ToInt32(p[1][1]-p[1][j]+1);
            int num_t2_options=Convert.ToInt32(p[3][1]-p[3][j]+1);

            double[][] f=new double [num_t1_options][];
            for (int i=0; i<num_t1_options; i++)
                f[i]=new double [num_t2_options];

            double dinamicMakeSpan;
            double t1 = p[1][1];
            double t2 = p[3][1];
            //DP(<current job #>,<t1>,<t2>,<ref to matrix P>)
            for (t1 = p[1][j]; t1 <= p[1][1]; t1++)
                for (t2 = p[3][j]; t2 <= p[3][1]; t2++)
                    f[Convert.ToInt32(t1 - p[1][j])][Convert.ToInt32(t2 - p[3][j])] = DP(j, t1, t2, ref p);

            double[] minArray = new double[num_t1_options];
            for (int i = 0; i < num_t1_options; i++)
                minArray[i] = f[i].Min();
            dinamicMakeSpan = minArray.Min();

            //Print all answers
            /*
            int rowCount = num_t1_options;
            int colCount = num_t2_options;
            for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++)
            {
                Console.Write("MakeSpan: [");
                for (int col = 0; col < colCount - 1; col++)
                    Console.Write(String.Format("{0}, ", f[row][col]));
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}]", f[row][colCount - 1]));
            }
            */

            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Dynamic MakeSpan: {0}", dinamicMakeSpan));
        }

        private static double DP(int j, double t1, double t2, ref double[][] p)
        {
            if (j==1) //stop condition
            {
                if (t1 == p[1][1] && t2 == p[3][1])
                    return p[1][1] + p[2][1] + p[3][1];

                return 9999999999;
            }

            int num_t1_options = Convert.ToInt32(p[1][1] - p[1][j] + 1);
            int num_t2_options = Convert.ToInt32(p[3][1] - p[3][j] + 1);
            double[][] f = new double[num_t1_options][];
            for (int i = 0; i < num_t1_options; i++)
                f[i] = new double[num_t2_options];

            for (t1=p[1][j]; t1<=p[1][1]; t1++)
                for (t2=p[3][j]; t2<=p[3][1]; t2++)
                {

                    if (t1>p[1][j] && t2>p[3][j])  //case 1
                        f[Convert.ToInt32(t1 - p[1][j])][Convert.ToInt32(t2 - p[3][j])]= Math.Min( p[1][j]+DP(j-1,t1+p[2][j]-p[1][j], t2,ref p),    p[3][j]+DP(j-1,t1, t2+p[2][j]-p[3][j],ref p));


                    double [] left; double [] right;
                    double min_job=p[1][p[0].Length-1];
                    int i,size;

                    if (t1==p[1][j] && t2>p[3][j]){  //case 2

                        size =Convert.ToInt32(p[2][j]-min_job +1);
                        left = new double[size];
                        for (double t=min_job; t<=p[2][j]; t++){
                            i = Convert.ToInt32(t-min_job);
                            left[i]=p[1][j]+p[2][j]-t+DP(j-1,t,t2,ref p);
                        }
                        f[Convert.ToInt32(t1 - p[1][j])][Convert.ToInt32(t2 - p[3][j])]= Math.Min(left.Min(), p[3][j]+DP(j-1, p[1][j], t2+p[2][j]-p[3][j], ref p));
                    }//case 2

                     if (t1>p[1][j] && t2==p[3][j]){  //case 3
                        min_job=p[3][p[0].Length-1];
                        size =Convert.ToInt32(p[2][j]-min_job +1);
                        right = new double[size];
                        for (double t=min_job; t<=p[2][j]; t++){
                            i = Convert.ToInt32(t-min_job);
                            right[i]=p[3][j]+p[2][j]-t+DP(j-1,t1,t,ref p);
                        }
                        f[Convert.ToInt32(t1 - p[1][j])][Convert.ToInt32(t2 - p[3][j])]= Math.Min(right.Min(), p[1][j]+DP(j-1, t1+p[2][j]-p[1][j], t2, ref p));
                     }//case 3

                      if (t1==p[1][j] && t2==p[3][j]){  //case 4
                        min_job=p[1][p[0].Length-1];
                        size =Convert.ToInt32(p[2][j]-min_job +1);
                        left = new double[size];
                        for (double t=min_job; t<=p[2][j]; t++){
                            i = Convert.ToInt32(t-min_job);
                            left[i]=p[1][j]+p[2][j]-t+DP(j-1,t,p[3][j],ref p);
                        }

                        min_job=p[3][p[0].Length-1];
                        size =Convert.ToInt32(p[2][j]-min_job +1);
                        right = new double[size];
                        for (double t=min_job; t<=p[2][j]; t++){
                            i = Convert.ToInt32(t-min_job);
                            right[i]=p[3][j]+p[2][j]-t+DP(j-1,p[1][j],t,ref p);
                        }

                        f[Convert.ToInt32(t1 - p[1][j])][Convert.ToInt32(t2 - p[3][j])]= Math.Min(right.Min(), left.Min());  
                      }//case 4
                }// end for for
            double[] minArray = new double[num_t1_options];
            for (int i = 0; i < num_t1_options; i++)
                minArray[i] = f[i].Min();
            double dinamicMakeSpan = minArray.Min();
            return dinamicMakeSpan;
        }//end DP

        private static double[][] MakeP(double[] jobs, double[] mashines_rates) //return matrix with indexes starts from 1 and not from 0 
        {
            double[][] p;
            p = new double[mashines_rates.Length+1][];
            for (int i = 0; i <= mashines_rates.Length; i++)
                p[i] = new double[jobs.Length+1];

            for (int i = 0; i < mashines_rates.Length; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < jobs.Length; j++)
                    p[i+1][j+1] = jobs[j] / mashines_rates[i];
            return p;
        }

        private static void manualRun(double[] jobs, double[] mashines_rates)
        {
            int num_of_vars = Factorial(jobs.Length);
            int num_of_jobs = jobs.Length;
            double[] heuristics = jobs;
            double[] heuristics_left;
            double[] heuristics_right;
            MergeSort_Recursive(heuristics, 0, jobs.Length - 1);
            Array.Reverse(heuristics);
            heuristics_left = schedule_left(heuristics);
            heuristics_right = schedule_right(heuristics);
            double makeSpan_left = find_MakeSpan(heuristics_left, mashines_rates);
            double makeSpan_right = find_MakeSpan(heuristics_right, mashines_rates);
            double makeSpan_heuristics;
            if (makeSpan_left < makeSpan_right)
            {
                makeSpan_heuristics = makeSpan_left;
                heuristics = heuristics_left;
            }
            else
            {
                makeSpan_heuristics = makeSpan_right;
                heuristics = heuristics_right;
            }


            double[][] jobs_var = make_job_variables(jobs);

            for (int i = 0; i < num_of_vars; i++)
            {
                jobs_var[i][num_of_jobs] = find_MakeSpan(jobs_var[i], mashines_rates);
            }
            sort__array_by_makeSpan<double>(jobs_var, num_of_jobs);


            double lowerBound = calcLowerBound(jobs, mashines_rates);
            double OG = jobs_var[0][num_of_jobs] / lowerBound;
            double HO = makeSpan_heuristics / jobs_var[0][num_of_jobs];
            double HLB = makeSpan_heuristics / lowerBound;

            PrintAnswer(jobs_var);

            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Lower Bound: {0}", lowerBound));
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("OG: {0}", OG));
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("HO: {0}", HO));
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("HLB: {0}", HLB));

            /*
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("makeSpan_heuristics: {0}", makeSpan_heuristics));
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("jobs_var[0][num_of_jobs]: {0}", jobs_var[0][num_of_jobs]));
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("makeSpan_left: {0}", makeSpan_left));
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("makeSpan_right: {0}", makeSpan_right));
            */
            int colCount = heuristics.Length;
            Console.Write(String.Format("makeSpan_heuristics: {0}, flow: [", makeSpan_heuristics));
            for (int col = 0; col < colCount-1 ; col++)
                Console.Write(String.Format("{0}, ", heuristics[col]));

            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}]", heuristics[colCount - 1]));


        }

        private static double [][] autoRun(double[][] examples, double[] mashines_rates)
        {
            int num_of_jobs = examples[0].Length;
            int num_of_machines = mashines_rates.Length;
            int num_of_vars = Factorial(num_of_jobs);
            double[] jobs;
            double[] heuristics;
            double[] heuristics_left;
            double[] heuristics_right;
            double makeSpan_left;
            double makeSpan_right;
            double makeSpan_heuristics;
            double makeSpan_optimum;
            double[][] jobs_var;
            double lowerBound;
            double OG;
            double HO;
            double HLB;
            double[][] answer_array = new double[examples.Length][];
            for (int i = 0; i < examples.Length; i++)
            {
                answer_array[i] = new double[6 + num_of_jobs*2];
            }


            for (int i = 0; i < examples.Length; i++)
            {
                jobs = new double[num_of_jobs];
                for (int job = 0; job < num_of_jobs; job++)
                {
                    jobs[job] = examples[i][job];
                }

                #region Make heuristic answer
                    heuristics = jobs;
                    MergeSort_Recursive(heuristics, 0, jobs.Length - 1);
                    Array.Reverse(heuristics);
                    heuristics_left = schedule_left(heuristics);
                    heuristics_right = schedule_right(heuristics);
                    makeSpan_left = find_MakeSpan(heuristics_left, mashines_rates);
                    makeSpan_right = find_MakeSpan(heuristics_right, mashines_rates);
                    if (makeSpan_left < makeSpan_right)
                    {
                        makeSpan_heuristics = makeSpan_left;
                        heuristics = heuristics_left;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        makeSpan_heuristics = makeSpan_right;
                        heuristics = heuristics_right;
                    }
                #endregion

                #region Make optimum answer
                    jobs_var = make_job_variables(jobs);
                    for (int k = 0; k < num_of_vars; k++)
                    {
                        jobs_var[k][num_of_jobs] = find_MakeSpan(jobs_var[k], mashines_rates);
                    }
                    sort__array_by_makeSpan<double>(jobs_var, num_of_jobs);
                #endregion


                lowerBound = calcLowerBound(jobs, mashines_rates);
                makeSpan_optimum=jobs_var[0][num_of_jobs];
                OG =  makeSpan_optimum/ lowerBound;
                HO = makeSpan_heuristics / makeSpan_optimum;
                HLB = makeSpan_heuristics / lowerBound;

                answer_array[i][0] = makeSpan_optimum;
                answer_array[i][1] = makeSpan_heuristics;
                answer_array[i][2] = lowerBound;
                answer_array[i][3] = OG;
                answer_array[i][4] = HO;
                answer_array[i][5] = HLB;
                for (int p = 0; p < num_of_jobs; p++)
                {
                    answer_array[i][p + 6] = jobs_var[0][p];
                }
                for (int p = 0; p < num_of_jobs; p++)
                {
                    answer_array[i][p + 6 + num_of_jobs] = heuristics[p];
                }


                //SaveExample(heuristics, makeSpan_heuristics, jobs, lowerBound);

                /*
                if (OG < 1) //if Lower Bound is fail
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("LowerBound is fail!");
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Optimum: {0}", jobs_var[0][num_of_jobs]));
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("lowerBound: {0}", lowerBound));

                    int colCount = jobs_var[0].Length - 1;
                    Console.Write(String.Format("MakeSpan: {0}, flow: [", jobs_var[0][colCount]));
                    for (int col = 0; col < colCount - 1; col++)
                        Console.Write(String.Format("{0}, ", jobs_var[0][col]));

                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}]", jobs_var[0][colCount - 1]));
                    Console.ReadKey();
                } */
            }
            return answer_array;
        }


        private static double[] schedule_right(double[] heuristics)
        {
            double[] scheduled = new double[heuristics.Length];
            if (heuristics.Length % 2 == 0)
            {
                int place = heuristics.Length / 2 ;
                scheduled[place] = heuristics[0];
                int counter = 1;
                int job_counter = 1;
                for (int i = 1; i < heuristics.Length; i++)
                {
                    scheduled[place - counter] = heuristics[i];
                    job_counter++;
                    if (job_counter < heuristics.Length)
                    {
                        scheduled[place + counter] = heuristics[i + 1];
                        job_counter++;
                        i++;
                    }
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                int counter = 1;
                int place = heuristics.Length / 2;
                scheduled[place] = heuristics[0];
                for (int i = 1; i < heuristics.Length; i++)
                {
                    scheduled[place + counter] = heuristics[i];
                    i++;
                    scheduled[place - counter] = heuristics[i];
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            return scheduled;
        }

        private static double calcLowerBound(double[] jobs, double[] mashines_rates)
        {
            double[] averages = new double[jobs.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < jobs.Length; i++)
            {
                averages[i] = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < mashines_rates.Length; j++)
                {
                    averages[i] += jobs[i] / mashines_rates[j];
                }
                averages[i] = averages[i] / mashines_rates.Length;
            }
            //double answer = averages.Sum() + averages.Max() * (mashines_rates.Length - 1);
            double average = averages.Sum() / averages.Length;
            double lowerBound = average * averages.Length + average * (mashines_rates.Length - 1);
            //Console.Write(String.Format("Lower Bound: {0}", lowerBound));
            return lowerBound;

        }

        private static void sort__array_by_makeSpan<T>(T[][] jobs_var, int col) 
        {
            Comparer<T> comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;
            Array.Sort<T[]>(jobs_var, (x, y) => comparer.Compare(x[col], y[col])); 
        }

        private static void PrintAnswer(double[][] jobs_var)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            int rowCount = Math.Min(40,jobs_var.Length);
            int colCount = jobs_var[0].Length-1;
            for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++)
            {
                Console.Write(String.Format("MakeSpan: {0}, flow: [", jobs_var[row][colCount]));
                for (int col = 0; col < colCount-1; col++)
                    Console.Write(String.Format("{0}, ", jobs_var[row][col]));

                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}]", jobs_var[row][colCount-1]));
            }
        }

        private static void PrintHeuristicAnswer(double[] jobs_var)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();

            int colCount = jobs_var.Length - 1;
            Console.Write(String.Format("MakeSpan: {0}, flow: [", jobs_var[colCount]));
            for (int col = 0; col < colCount - 1; col++)
                Console.Write(String.Format("{0}, ", jobs_var[col]));
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}]", jobs_var[colCount - 1]));
        }

        private static double find_MakeSpan(double[] jobs_array, double[] mashines_rates)
        {
            int num_of_jobs = jobs_array.Length;
            int num_of_machines = mashines_rates.Length;
            double[] flows = new double[num_of_machines];
            double makespan;
            for (int i = 0; i < num_of_machines; i++)
            {
                flows[i] = 0;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < num_of_jobs; i++)
            {
                flows[0] += jobs_array[i] / mashines_rates[0];
                for (int j = 1; j < num_of_machines; j++)
                {
                    flows[j] = Math.Max(flows[j - 1], flows[j]) + jobs_array[i] / mashines_rates[j];
                }
            }
            makespan = flows[num_of_machines - 1];
            return makespan;
        }

        private static int Factorial(int i)
        {
            if (i <= 1)
            return 1;
            return i * Factorial(i - 1);   
        }

        private static double[][] make_job_variables(double[] jobs)
        {
            double[][] jobs_vars;
            int num_of_vars=Factorial(jobs.Length);
            jobs_vars = new double[num_of_vars][];
            for (int i=0; i<num_of_vars; i++){
                jobs_vars[i] = new double[jobs.Length + 1];
                jobs_vars[i][jobs.Length] = 0;
            }
            int count = 0;
            foreach (double[] permutation in Permutations<double>.AllFor(jobs))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < jobs.Length; i++)
                {
                    jobs_vars[count][i] = permutation[i];
                }
                count++;
            }
            return jobs_vars;
        }

        static public void DoMerge(double[] numbers, int left, int mid, int right)
        {
            double[] temp = new double[25];
            int i, left_end, num_elements, tmp_pos;
            left_end = (mid - 1);
            tmp_pos = left;
            num_elements = (right - left + 1);
            while ((left <= left_end) && (mid <= right))
            {
                if (numbers[left] <= numbers[mid])
                    temp[tmp_pos++] = numbers[left++];
                else
                    temp[tmp_pos++] = numbers[mid++];
            }
            while (left <= left_end)
                temp[tmp_pos++] = numbers[left++];
            while (mid <= right)
                temp[tmp_pos++] = numbers[mid++];
            for (i = 0; i < num_elements; i++)
            {
                numbers[right] = temp[right];
                right--;
            }
        }

        static public void MergeSort_Recursive(double[] numbers, int left, int right)
        {

            int mid;
            if (right > left)
            {
                mid = (right + left) / 2;
                MergeSort_Recursive(numbers, left, mid);
                MergeSort_Recursive(numbers, (mid + 1), right);
                DoMerge(numbers, left, (mid + 1), right);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Permutations<T>
    {
        public static System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T[]> AllFor(T[] array)
        {
            if (array == null || array.Length == 0)
            {
                yield return new T[0];
            }
            else
            {
                for (int pick = 0; pick < array.Length; ++pick)
                {
                    T item = array[pick];
                    int i = -1;
                    T[] rest = System.Array.FindAll<T>(
                        array, delegate(T p) { return ++i != pick; }
                    );
                    foreach (T[] restPermuted in AllFor(rest))
                    {
                        i = -1;
                        yield return System.Array.ConvertAll<T, T>(
                            array,
                            delegate(T p)
                            {
                                return ++i == 0 ? item : restPermuted[i - 1];
                            }
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried profiling your code?

Comment: I see lots of extra writelines and writes in nested loops, while the code is also written in a non-object-oriented manner (enough so that I'm starting to wonder why you're even using C#!). Wouldn't one `Console.Write("\n\n\n")` be clearer than triple writelines? Maybe moreso as a method? Can't all your regions be methods? I expect many won't want to review it before at least that much is done.

Comment: Definitely run this through a performance profiler, the one built into VS2012 works great for .net assemblies (Analyze > Launch Performance Wizard).

Comment: I'm afraid this question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving the cleanliness of **existing and working code**. Code Review is not the site to ask for help in fixing or changing what your code does. Once the code does what you want, we would love to help you to do the same thing in a cleaner way!

Comment: The `schedule_left` function is missing.

Comment: The `CreateOutputFile()` method is missing also

Comment: You have inconsistent use of braces in your if/else statements. Regions are code smell and indicate that you should use a method.

Don't ommit braces after if's and for's it can lead to problems down the road.

Use var on the left hand side of a variable declaration when the type is declared on the right hand side.

Comment: What exactly *is* "Three-machine proportionate flow shop problem with unequal machine"? I would like to see more description about that in your question.

Answer (score 6):

**Missing methods**

The posted code is missing the `schedule_left()` and `CreateOutputFile()` method.

**Style**

- you should always be consistent in the style you use. Switching from not using braces `{}` to using them for single `for` loops should be avoided. The same is true for single `if` statements.
- dead code should be deleted
- if you decide to **not using braces** for single `if` statements you should indent your code. See

  > ```
  > private static int Factorial(int i)
  > {
  >     if (i <= 1)
  >     return 1;
  >     return i * Factorial(i - 1);   
  > }
  > ```
- using `region`'s is discussed controversially, but using `region`'s inside a method is a sign that this "region" should be extracted to its own method.

**Naming**

Reading and understanding is all about words we use e.g to explain a question and its solution. These words needs to be meaningful to the reader as well as to the author.
Shortening these names to e.g `p` doesn't add readability but removes it.

Based on the [naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx) methods should be named using `PascalCase` casing and should be made out of verbs or verb phrases. Fields or variable should be named using `camelCase` casing. `snake_Case` casing isn't used in C#.

**General**

- you shouldn't add references you don't use. -> `using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;`
- you have many magic numbers in your code. You should consider to extract them into meaningful constants.
- if you read input from the user, you need to add some sort of validation. Instead of blindly calling `Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())` you should use [`Int32.TryParse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
- you should extract the reading of the users input to a separate method like for `Int32`

  ```
  private static Int32 ReadInt32(String message, String errorMessage)
  {
      Console.WriteLine(message);
      Int32 input;
      while (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input))
      {
          Console.WriteLine(errorMessage);
      }
      return input;
  }
  ```

  which you then call like

  ```
  int num_of_ex = ReadInt32("How many examples do you want to run? ", "You need to input a valid number, please try again.");
  ```
- starting a `for` loop by `1` for filling an array is strange.

  ```
  for (int size = 1; size <= num_of_jobs; size++)
  {
      Console.Write("The process time of job number " + size+": ");
      jobs[size-1] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
  }
  ```

  it would be better by renaming the iteration variable and also by calling a `ReadDouble()` method like

  ```
  for (int jobIndex = 0; jobIndex < num_of_jobs; jobIndex++)
  {
      jobs[jobIndex] = ReadDouble(String.Format("The process time of job number {0}: ", jobIndex + 1), "You need to input a valid number, please try again.");
  }
  ```

**DynamicProgramming()**

- this method is badly named because it isn't clear by this name what the method should do.
- the code of creating the jagged array `f` is the same as in the `DP()` method, so this should be extracted to a separate method to remove code duplication.

  ```
  private static double[][] GetJaggedArray(int firstDimensionLength, int secondDimensionLength)
  {
      double[][] jaggedArray = new double[firstDimensionLength][];
      for (int i = 0; i < firstDimensionLength; i++)
      {
          jaggedArray[i] = new double[secondDimensionLength];
      }
      return jaggedArray;
  }
  ```
- the declaration of the loop variables `t1` and `t2` should be done in the loop itself.
- the repeated use of `p[1][j]` and `p[3][j]` where `j == p[0].Length - 1` asks for separate variables.
- to get the upper bound of an array we can use the `GetUpperBound()` method.
- if we use `Math.Min()` we can omit the `minArray` and because this is used in `DP()` also, we extract it to its own method

  ```
  private static double GetMinimum(double[][] array)
  {
      double minimum = double.MaxValue;
      for (int i = 0; i < array.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
      {
          minimum = Math.Min(minimum, array[i].Min());
      }
      return minimum;
  }
  ```
- there is no need to call for each iteration of the inner loop `Convert.ToInt32(t1 - p[1][j])` because this won't change. So better extract it to a variable which is set in the outer loop.

Implemented all above will lead to

```
private static void DynamicProgramming(double[][] p)
{

    int last = p[0].GetUpperBound(0);

    double pOneLast = p[1][last];
    double pThreeLast = p[3][last];

    int num_t1_options = Convert.ToInt32(p[1][1] - pOneLast + 1);
    int num_t2_options = Convert.ToInt32(p[3][1] - pThreeLast + 1);

    double[][] f = GetJaggedArray(num_t1_options, num_t2_options);

    for (double t1 = pOneLast; t1 <= p[1][1]; t1++)
    {
        int firstIndex = Convert.ToInt32(t1 - pOneLast);
        for (double t2 = pThreeLast; t2 <= p[3][1]; t2++)
        {
            f[firstIndex][Convert.ToInt32(t2 - pThreeLast)] = DP(last, t1, t2, ref p);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Dynamic MakeSpan: {0}", GetMinimum(f)));
}
```

**DP()**

- the `ref` keyword is not necessary.
- multiple declarations in one line should be avoided
- also there is no rule for where to place the opening bracket `{` most place it on the new line. If you choose one style you should be consistent.
- because the element of `f` which is set is always the "same" `f[Convert.ToInt32(t1 - p[1][j])][Convert.ToInt32(t2 - p[3][j])]` we can extract these indices to separate variables to make the code more readable

  ```
  double pOneLast = p[1][j];
  double pThreeLast = p[3][j];

  int firstIndex = Convert.ToInt32(t1 - pOneLast);
  int secondIndex = Convert.ToInt32(t2 - pThreeLast);
  ```
- if we now take a look at the `case 1`'s condition `if (t1 > p[1][j] && t2 > p[3][j])` which is now `if (t1 > pOneLast && t2 > pThreeLast)` we can change it to `if (firstIndex > 0 && secondIndex > 0)`. This can be done for the other cases too.

  If we extract the processing of the different cases to separate methods like

  ```
  private static double ProcessBothNonZero(int j, double t1, double t2, double[][] p)
  {
      double pOneLast = p[1][j];
      double pThreeLast = p[3][j];

      double firstDP = DP(j - 1, t1 + p[2][j] - pOneLast, t2, ref p);
      double secondDP = DP(j - 1, t1, t2 + p[2][j] - pThreeLast, ref p);

      return Math.Min(pOneLast + firstDP, pThreeLast + secondDP);
  }

  private static double ProcessFirstIsZero(int j, double t1, double t2, double[][] p)
  {
      double pOneLast = p[1][j];
      double pTwoLast = p[2][j];
      double pThreeLast = p[3][j];

      double min_job = p[1][p[0].Length - 1];
      double result = double.MaxValue;

      for (double t = min_job; t <= pTwoLast; t++)
      {
          double firstDP = DP(j - 1, t, t2, ref p);
          result = Math.Min(result, pOneLast + pTwoLast - t + firstDP);
      }

      double secondDP = DP(j - 1, pOneLast, t2 + pTwoLast - pThreeLast, ref p);

      return Math.Min(result, pThreeLast + secondDP);
  }
  private static double ProcessSecondIsZero(int j, double t1, double t2, double[][] p)
  {
      double pOneLast = p[1][j];
      double pTwoLast = p[2][j];
      double pThreeLast = p[3][j];
      double result = double.MaxValue;
      double min_job = p[3][p[0].Length - 1];

      for (double t = min_job; t <= pTwoLast; t++)
      {
          double firstDP = DP(j - 1, t1, t, ref p);
          result = Math.Min(result, pThreeLast + pTwoLast - t + firstDP);
      }
      double secondDP = DP(j - 1, t1 + pTwoLast - pOneLast, t2, ref p);
      return Math.Min(result, pOneLast + secondDP);

  }
  private static double ProcessBothAreZero(int j, double t1, double t2, double[][] p)
  {
      double pOneLast = p[1][j];
      double pTwoLast = p[2][j];
      double pThreeLast = p[3][j];
      double min_job = p[1][p[0].Length - 1];
      double result = double.MaxValue;

      for (double t = min_job; t <= pTwoLast; t++)
      {
          double firstDP = DP(j - 1, t, pThreeLast, ref p);
          result = Math.Min(result, pOneLast + pTwoLast - t + firstDP);
      }

      min_job = p[3][p[0].Length - 1];

      for (double t = min_job; t <= p[2][j]; t++)
      {
          double secondDP = DP(j - 1, pOneLast, t, ref p);
          result = Math.Min(result, pThreeLast + pTwoLast - t + secondDP);
      }

      return result;
  }
  ```

  Yes, I know they are named poorly but without having enough domain specific knowledge this can happen.

  The former `DP()` method will then look like

  ```
  private static double DP(int j, double t1, double t2, ref double[][] p)
  {

      if (j == 1)
      {
          if (t1 == p[1][1] && t2 == p[3][1])
          {
              return p[1][1] + p[2][1] + p[3][1];
          }
          return double.MaxValue;
      }

      double pOneLast = p[1][j];
      double pThreeLast = p[3][j];

      int num_t1_options = Convert.ToInt32(p[1][1] - pOneLast + 1);
      int num_t2_options = Convert.ToInt32(p[3][1] - pThreeLast + 1);

      double[][] f = GetJaggedArray(num_t1_options, num_t2_options);

      for (t1 = pOneLast; t1 <= p[1][1]; t1++)
      {
          int firstIndex = Convert.ToInt32(t1 - pOneLast);
          for (t2 = pThreeLast; t2 <= p[3][1]; t2++)
          {
              int secondIndex = Convert.ToInt32(t2 - pThreeLast);

              if (firstIndex > 0 && secondIndex > 0)
              {
                  f[firstIndex][secondIndex] = ProcessBothNonZero(j, t1, t2, p);
              }

              if (firstIndex == 0 && secondIndex > 0)
              {
                  f[firstIndex][secondIndex] = ProcessFirstIsZero(j, t1, t2, p);
              }

              if (firstIndex > 0 && secondIndex == 0)
              {
                  f[firstIndex][secondIndex] = ProcessSecondIsZero(j, t1, t2, p);
              }

              if (firstIndex == 0 && secondIndex == 0)
              {
                  f[firstIndex][secondIndex] = ProcessBothAreZero(j, t1, t2, p);
              }
          }
      }
      return GetMinimum(f);
  }
  ```

**MakeP()**

Using the new `GetJaggedArray()` method, this can be simplified to

```
/// <summary>
/// return matrix with indexes starts from 1
/// </summary>
private static double[][] MakeP(double[] jobs, double[] mashines_rates)
{
    double[][] p = GetJaggedArray(mashines_rates.Length + 1, jobs.Length + 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < mashines_rates.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < jobs.Length; j++)
        {
            p[i + 1][j + 1] = jobs[j] / mashines_rates[i];
        }
    }
    return p;
}
```

**calcLowerBound()**

By renaming the method to `CalculateLowerBound()` and extracting the calculation of the average to a separate method the former `calcLowerBound()` method is much more readable.

```
private static double CalculateLowerBound(double[] jobs, double[] mashines_rates)
{
    double average = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < jobs.Length; i++)
    {
        average += GetAverage(jobs[i], mashines_rates);
    }
    average = average / jobs.Length;
    return average * jobs.Length + average * (mashines_rates.Length - 1);
}
private static double GetAverage(double job, double[] maschineRates)
{
    double average = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < maschineRates.Length; j++)
    {
        average += job / maschineRates[j];
    }
    return average / maschineRates.Length;
}
```

**find_MakeSpan()**

By removing the not needed initialisation `for` loop and directly returning the result this can be simplified to

```
    private static double Find_MakeSpan(double[] jobs, double[] machineRates)
    {
        int numberOfJobs = jobs.Length;
        int numberOfMachines = machineRates.Length;
        double[] flows = new double[numberOfMachines];
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfJobs; i++)
        {
            flows[0] += jobs[i] / machineRates[0];
            for (int j = 1; j < numberOfMachines; j++)
            {
                flows[j] = Math.Max(flows[j - 1], flows[j]) + jobs[i] / machineRates[j];
            }
        }
        return flows[numberOfMachines - 1];
    }
```

**make_job_variables()**

By renaming the method to `CreateJobVariables()` and removing the not needed initialisation `for` loop and using the new `GetJaggedArray()` method, this can be simplified to

```
private static double[][] CreateJobVariables(double[] jobs)
{

    int num_of_vars = Factorial(jobs.Length);
    double[][] jobs_vars = GetJaggedArray(num_of_vars, jobs.Length + 1);

    int count = 0;
    foreach (double[] permutation in Permutations<double>.AllFor(jobs))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < jobs.Length; i++)
        {
            jobs_vars[count][i] = permutation[i];
        }
        count++;
    }
    return jobs_vars;
}
```